# What are these displays called?

Tags: identification, display

I now searched the web for about an hour and just can't figure out how these displays are called or where to buy them.

A lot of airports use them for the departure table.
They seem to be just LED-Displays with a really strange dot layout.

Does anybody have an idea how these displays or these dot alignments are called?

[image]
<sub>(source: [thehindu.com](http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/00119/AVN_ASHCANCEL_119003f.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Flip display, flip dots display, something like that I think.

Comment: @Sergio: No, flip dots are actual dots. The OP's display is a custom LCD.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image appears to have succumbed to link rot and the wayback machine doesn't have it archived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really interesting Google challenge.

I think it may be LCD - see this patent (EP 0146285 A2):

http://www.google.co.uk/patents/EP0146285A2?cl=en

This one has what looks like a very similar pixel arrangement:

http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US5497171

And here is a brochure where they're described as 'mosaic modules':

http://www.drpmgmt.com/files/LCD.pdf

Somewhat ironically, given the earlier answer which has now been deleted, these appear to be made by Solari, though they're absolutely NOT what people generically refer to as a 'Solari Display'.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for.

But it seems rather impossible to get such a thing as a hobbyist. Any ideas?

Comment: The only one I found was this:  http://www.giant-supplier.com/LCDDisplay.htm which is a two-char 111mm high module